# How can I create a two dimensional array with each element being a list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I want to create a two-dimensional array, each element of which is a list, as in the image.
I tried `ArrayList<List<User>>[][] arrayList = new ArrayList[3][3];`

Is this a correct solution? Because when I try to add element like below code I get null error.

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
arrayList[0][0].add(list);
User user = new User(1,3,2,6);
arrayList[0][0].get(0).add(user);
System.out.println(arrayList[0][0].get(0).get(0).id);
```

[image]

Comment: When asking a question please provide a reproducibl example, here missing the User class

Comment: Where is arrayList defined ?

Comment: In each box a the 2D array : there is a 1D or a 2D list ? Because what you write ends up in a 4-dimension structure

Comment: `arrayList[0][0].add(list);`  Your "arrayList" which is actually an array doesn't have methods.  You just assign a reference.  `arrayList[0][0]  = list;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles and runs for me.  Note I changed your definition of "arrayList" to match your diagram better.  I think this is what you want.  However it's simple to extend if you need something different.

```
public class ArrayOfList {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      ArrayList<User>[][] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList[ 3 ][ 3 ];
      ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
      arrayOfLists[0][0] = list;
      User user = new User( 1, 3, 2, 6 );
      arrayOfLists[0][0].add( user );
      System.out.println( arrayOfLists[0][0].get( 0 ).id );
   }

}
```